# Send an encrypted form data from an html to a new url

Tags: html, encryption, django-templates

I fill a form, use the form data to do some stuff and display the output to the user in an html file.

In the same output html file I want to send the form data to another url so as to reuse the data in another view but how can I encrypt the data and send as it contains username's password's.

my **done.html**

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h2> Thanks </h2>
    <h2> Output </h2>
        {{output}}
    <form action="/confirm/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <textarea name="content" rows="25" cols="60">{{form_data}}
        </textarea><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Yes"/>
    </form>
    <form action="/admin/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="No"/>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

the {{form_data}} in the above html needs to be encrypted as its shows exactly what the user has entered when the html is displayed.

Can you people please help me out how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I can think of doing this is changing the method to GET instead of post. However this will be in raw text. You could first have the form submit to the MySQL database, then have the form go to the URL of the database entries ID.

For example if I was the first person to fill the form out and I filled it out that information would get stored in a database. Then when I navigate to a new URL the new URL would go to something like the following.

www.example.com?id=1

This would be assuming that the database entry is the first entry and has primary key. Then it will fetch that information from the database and display it.

Another route to go would be using cookies some way or another.

Answer (score 0):

Use SSL, and use POST not GET since GET is cached and a history is created in the browser.

SSL will encrypt communications between the client and the server.  You'll need to get this setup on your server however, but for encrypting communication between client and server it is the most accepted method.  I highly recommend you **don't** try to do the encryption yourself on the client side before sending the data.

You should also check the user is using SSL from your server-side script and redirect them to the SSL version of the page if they are not.